# Probabilistic Running Based on Percentage in C

Tags: c, random, probability

I am reviewing a code which I believe runs based on probability. I would like to verify that if it is true. Does the following code snippet runs 80% of the time? I dont quite get why use 1000 then if our job is to merely run a code 80% of the time.

```
if(rand()%1000<1000*0.8){
 ...
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will run approximately 80% of the time.

- `rand()` returns a number between 0 and `RAND_MAX` which is probably 2,147,483,647
- `rand() % 1000` reduces that range to 0-999, although some numbers in the first half or so of the range will be slightly more common because `RAND_MAX` is not evenly divisible by 1,000
- `1000 * 0.8` is just 800

The use of 1,000 here is arbitrary. A clearer way of representing 80% would be:

```
if (rand() % 100 < 80)
```

or just:

```
if (rand() < RAND_MAX * 0.8)
```

Comment: yes, the last syntax is more understandable. I dont know why author wrote with 1000